# roscpp Callback Thread Safety SEGFAULT

Tags: ros, roscpp, asyncspinner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently subscribing to every topic ever published in my program via `ShapeShifter`, and deserializing as necessary. This works great, but I'm receiving SEGFAULTs when using `ros::AsyncSpinner`. I'm essentially trying to create a live rqt_graph, which monitors latency between sent and received messages.

Why is the below not threadsafe? From my console, it looks like the shared::ptr to `Shapeshifter` msg within my callback get changed on me without me finishing the callback. Is it not safe to pass shared::ptr to ROS callback threads?

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffea7fc700 (LWP 31281)]
__memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:79
79  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
```

**MAIN**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "performance_tracker_node");

  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(4);
  spinner.start();

  // Loop on the main thread and search for new topics being published
  // If the topic caught doesn't exist in our Node list yet, add it
  while(ros::ok()){
       //Code that finds new topics not included
                PerformanceTracker newNode = PerformanceTracker(info.name);
                performanceNodes.insert(std::pair<std::string, PerformanceTracker>(info.name, newNode));
     }
      ros::waitForShutdown;
}
```

**Performance Tracker Constructor**

```
PerformanceTracker::PerformanceTracker(std::string topicName):
_topicName(topicName)
 {
   ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
  _nh = nh;
  // Subscribe To Generic Message 
 _sub =  _nh.subscribe( _topicName, 10, &PerformanceTracker::topicCallback, this);
}
```

**Performance Tracker Callback**

```
void PerformanceTracker::topicCallback(const boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> msg){
//Current Time
ros::Time begin = ros::Time::now();

    //Prevent OOB error by only checking msgs that are at least the size of a header msg 
    if(msg->size() >= sizeof(std_msgs::Header)){
        //Deserialize message
        std_msgs::Header header;
        uint8_t buf[msg->size()];
        ros::serialization::OStream stream(buf, msg->size());
        msg->write(stream);
        header.seq = ((uint32_t *)buf)[0];
        header.stamp.sec = ((int32_t *)buf)[1];
        header.stamp.nsec = ((int32_t *)buf)[2];

        // Delays greater than 1 hour are clearly wrong., and the header doesn't exist, so skip this
        double lagTime = (begin-header.stamp).toSec();
        if(lagTime > 3600){
            // Skip this topic in the future
            std::cout << "Topic " << _topicName <<  " sent at " <<  header.stamp << " returned nonsense time for " << lagTime <<  " seconds" << std::endl;
            _nh.shutdown();
        }
       //if delayed, then log time lag
        else if(lagTime > 1){
            std::cout << "Topic " << _topicName <<  " sent at " <<  header.stamp << " delayed for" << lagTime <<  " seconds" << std::endl;
        }
    }
     // Remove topic for future if topic message type is too small 
    else{
        // Skip this topic in the future
        std::cout << "Topic " << _topicName <<  " message size was smaller than just a std::msg Header, and likely did not have a header "<< std::endl;
        _nh.shutdown();
    }
 }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227156/roscpp-callback-thread-safety-segfault/) by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`boost::shared_ptr` are explicitly designed to be shared between threads; the function prototype for your callback seems fine.

I would run your program through a debugger (gdb) to determine the location of the segfault.

(It's also odd that you're calling `_nh.shutdown()` when you want to unsubscribe from a single topic, because this will shut down your entire process; not just a single subscriber).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on 2016-02-20**:
I posted the error from gdb, Ill post the full stacktrace. I'm create a new `nodehandle` for each topic, and then calling shutdown(). Is that not allowed?  I wasn't aware of how to use only one nodehandle for the entire node and unsubscribe from a particular topic

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-21**:
roscpp only creates one node per process, regardless of how many NodeHandles you create. Calling shutdown on any NodeHandle shuts down the entire process. If you want to stop a particular subscriber, call the unsubscribe method on that subscriber.

**Comment by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on 2016-02-21**:
I don't see an unsubscribe member function on `ros::Subscriber`. I only see `shutdown`

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-21**:
Sorry; that's what I meant.

**Comment by [jlack](https://answers.ros.org/users/30932/jlack/) on 2017-11-14**:
Did you ever figure this out? I think i'm having the same problem.